# Draw image to canvas in particular order

Tags: javascript, canvas, onload

I am currently trying to draw some images on my canvas however the issue is that whenever the page loads, my drawings may not be in the order I want it to be (e.g. background loads first, then then fishes so fishes doesnt get hidden behind the background) Can someone please help me @.@ Thanks!

```
function placeBkg(){

    var background = new Image();
    background.src = 'static/img/bgocean.png';
    background.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);   
    }
}

function placeSwarm(i){  
                          
    var image = new Image();  
    image.src = 'static/img/3sprite.png';
    image.onload = function(){  
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
        ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high'; 
        ctx.drawImage(image,fishArray[i].x,fishArray[i].y,100,70);
    } 
 }

function placeShark(){   
                           
    var image = new Image(); 
    image.src = 'static/img/sprite.png';
    image.onload = function(){  
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
        ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';
        ctx.drawImage(image,1,150,200,200);
    } 
 } 

function placeStudentFish(){  //load image function 
                           //creates a new i each time it is called
    var image = new Image(); //create a new image
    image.src = 'static/img/2sprite.png';
    image.onload = function(){  
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
        ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high'; 
        ctx.drawImage(image,450,215,100,70);
    } 
 }
```

```
 placeBkg()
 placeShark();
 for(var i = 0; i < fishArray.length; i += 1){
    placeSwarm(i); // call the function so it can create unique variables for each image
}
placeStudentFish();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split images loading and drawing.

```js
var images = {
  background: 'static/img/bgocean.png',
  swarm: 'static/img/3sprite.png',
  shark: 'static/img/sprite.png',
  fish: 'static/img/2sprite.png'
};
for(let key in images){
  let image = new Image();
  image.src = images[key];
  image.onload = function(){
    images[key] = image;
    draw();
  };
}

var drawOrder = [ 
  {id: 'background', position: {x: 0, y: 0}},
  {id: 'shark', position: {x: 1, y: 150, w: 200, h: 200}},
  {id: 'swarm', position: fishArray.map( fish=>({x: fish.x, y: fish.y, w: 100, h: 70}) )},
  {id: 'fish', position: {x: 450, y: 215, w: 100, h: 70}},
];

ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high'; 

var current = 0;
var draw = function(){

  var step = drawOrder[current];
  if(typeof images[step.id] === 'string') return ; // not loaded yet
  console.log(step)
  if(!Array.isArray(step.position)) step.position = [step.position];

  step.position.forEach(pos => 
    'w' in pos
    ? ctx.drawImage(images[step.id], pos.x, pos.y, pos.w, pos.h)
    : ctx.drawImage(images[step.id], pos.x, pos.y)
  );

  current++;
  if(current < drawOrder.length)
    draw();
};
```

You can change steps of draw order to make the fish swim around. For redraw the whole scene — set `current = 0;` and recall `draw();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add them in a specific order, it would be best to use something asynchronous in my opinion. You could promisify loading the images by doing something like this

```js
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', () => {
      resolve(image);
    });
    image.addEventListener('error', reject);
    image.src = url;
  });
}
```

You can then use this in an async function to wait to load each image before placing and continuing to the next one. *This could be improved by loading them all at once using Promise.all but I won't show that here*

```js
async function placeImages() {
  const bkg = await loadImage('static/img/bgocean.png');
  ctx.drawImage(bkg, 0, 0);
  const shark = await loadImage('static/img/sprite.png');
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
  ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';
  ctx.drawImage(shark,1,150,200,200);
  // ...
}
```